# Beamer miniframes: horizontal space between dots when using the compress option

Tags: beamer, spacing, sections-paragraphs, mini-frames

I'm using the beamer miniframes theme (with subsection=false) and the compress option. Currently the navigation shows the dots for each subsection side-by-side. I would prefer if there would be a horizontal space (e.g. with the width of a dot) between the dots of each subsection. Is this possible?

Right now it looks like:

> Section 1
>
> oooooo

And I would prefer it to look like:

> Section 1
>
> ooo ooo

MWE:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}  
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}  
\begin{document}  
\section{Sec 1}  
\subsection{}  
\begin{frame}[t]  
  hi  
\end{frame}
\subsection{}  
\begin{frame}[t]  
  hi  
\end{frame}
\end{document}`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify the definition of `\slideentry`. You can see this command in the `.nav` file. This file is used to generate the dots.

The original definition is in `beamerbasenavigation.sty`. I add only three lines: those contain `%%%`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\makeatletter
\def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  %section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number
  \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#2>0\ifnum#3>0%
    \ifbeamer@compress%
      \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
      \ifnum1=#3                        %%% NOTICE
        \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax% %%% THESE
      \fi                               %%% LINE
    \else%
      \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
      \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
    \fi%
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
    \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
    \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
      \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
      \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
      \kern\beamer@tempdim
      \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
      \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
          \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
          \ifnum\c@section=#1%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=#2%
              \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
              \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=#3%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%\beamer@minislidehilight%
              \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}%\beamer@minisliderowhilight%
              \fi%
            \else%
              \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
              %\color{fg!50!bg}%
              \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
            \fi%
          \else%
            \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
            %\color{fg!50!bg}%
            \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
          \fi%
        }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
  }\fi\fi%
  \else%
  \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \fi\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
    \section{1}
        \subsection{1-1}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
        \subsection{1-2}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
        \subsection{1-3}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
    \section{2}
        \subsection{2-1}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
        \subsection{2-2}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
        \subsection{2-3}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
    \section{3}
        \subsection{3-1}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
        \subsection{3-2}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
        \subsection{3-3}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
            \frame{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer is almost perfect. I now understood the generation of the dots quite well.   
  
I just changed a little bit:  
`\ifnum1=#3 %%% NOTICE`  
    `\ifnum1=#2\else`  
        `\advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax% %%% THESE`  
    `\fi`  
    `\fi %%% LINE`  
to remove the white space before the dots of the very first subsection.

Comment: Slightly better: `\ifnum#2>1\ifnum#3=1\advance\beamer@xpos by 1\relax\fi\fi`.

Comment: One addition: If there is a \AtBeginSubsection[] frame with disabled miniframe dots is present, the line
`\ifnum1=#3`
must be changed to
`\ifnum2=#3`
as the additional space must be placed on the second slide of each new subsection.